# Dipole moment operator for many a electrons wave function

Tags: operators, electrons, dipole-moment

From textbooks (such as *Optical Spectroscopy of Inorganic*, Henderson, 2006) I know that the electric dipole moment operator is defined for one electron as:

$$
\hat{\mu} = e \hat{r}
$$

But then suppose I have a many electron wave function defined with a Slater determinant:
$$
\Psi = \{\phi_1, ..., \phi_n\}
$$

How do I define the dipole now?

My guts answer would simply be:

$$
\hat\mu = e\sum_i \hat{r}_i
$$

Which would lead to (wrong I think, see edit):

$$
\langle\hat\mu\rangle = e \sum_i \langle i | \hat{r}_i | i\rangle
$$

But that almost sounds too good to be true.

**Edit:**

Actually, I think the expected value would be:

$$
\langle\hat\mu\rangle = e \sum_{i,j} \langle i | \hat{r}_j | i\rangle
$$

because $\hat{r}_i$ would act on the first particle, but each base function participate to the first particle in the Slater determinant.

Which make we ask:
Then, would the operator rather be:

$$
\hat{\mu} = e \hat{r}_1
$$

such that

$$
\langle \hat\mu \rangle = e \sum_i \langle i | \hat{r}_1 | i\rangle
$$

Comment: why do you say this is too good to be true? looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen see my edits, I was wrong with my expected value and now I have two "reasonable" candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dipole moment operator for many a electrons wave function...
>
> My guts answer would simply be:
>
> $$
> \hat\mu = e\sum_i \hat{r}_i
> $$

Assuming that $e$ is equal to $-|e|$, the charge of an electron, then yes, this is the correct expression for the dipole moment (about zero) of a many-electron system.

Also, I am assuming your $\hat r_i$ is supposed to mean a vector of operators like $(X_i, Y_i, Z_i)$, not a unit vector. I might write this $\hat r_i$ more explicitly as $\hat{\vec r}_i$, but I admit that latter expression has an unfortunate number of symbols stacked vertically.

---

**Further Explanation:**

Suppose you have an $N$-electron wave function:
$$
\Psi(\vec r_1, \vec r_2,\ldots,\vec r_N)\;,
$$
which is assumed anti-symmetric in all its arguments. Therefore $|\Psi|^2$ is symmetric in all its arguments.

You can define an electron charge density $\rho(\vec r)$ as:
$$
\rho(\vec r) \equiv eN \int d^3 r_2 d^3r_3\ldots d^3r_N |\Psi(\vec r, \vec r_2,\ldots,\vec r_N)|^2\;,
$$
which has the expected property:
$$
\int d^3r \rho(\vec r) = eN \;.
$$

Now, you can write:
$$
\langle \vec \mu \rangle = e\int d^3r_1\ldots d^3r_N \sum_{i=1}^N\vec r_i|\Psi(\vec r_1, \ldots, \vec r_N)|^2
$$
$$
=eN \int d^3r \vec r\int d^3r_2\ldots d^3r_N|\Psi(\vec r, \vec r_2,\ldots, \vec r_N)|^2\tag{A}
$$
$$
=\int d^3r \vec r\rho(\vec r)\;,
$$
where we got the equation tagged (A) by using the symmetry of $|\Psi|^2$.